# Hierarchy Representation for finding leaves

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, data-representation

I have a number of hierarchies (trees) I am trying to represent in a relational database. The most important operation I will perform is: given a root node, find the leaves of the tree. Which hierarchy representation is best suited for this operation?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show us some code to visualise the hierarchy you have, queries you've already tried and what you expect as a result. Here is some useful tips on how to construct good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also what kind of SQL are we talking about here? MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL?

Comment: I am using SQL Server. I don't have any code yet because I'm in the process of designing a database. To better visualise the problem, imagine a forest of trees which share leaves. For each tree, I'm really only interested in getting to its leaves. Is there a representation which is particularly suited for this? Since all of the trees are fairly shallow (only 2 or 3 levels deep) and static (trees are based on definitions and will not change), I was thinking of simply enumerating all of the leaves for a given node in a  (node, leaf) table.

Comment: It will be very difficult to answer your question without a proper example, however, have you ever looked at CTE? It's called `Common Table Expressions` and I use them to produce hierarchical structures from one table using one query. Here's a helpful link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx You can also search Stack Overflow for lots of examples of CTE